# Convert array of strings into an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this JavaScript array:

```js
[
  "test: Yes, name: user1, number: +9190000000",
  "test: Yes, name: user2, number: +9162000000",
];
```

I want to convert this particular array into an array of objects as shown below:

```js
[
  { test: "Yes", name: "user1", number: "+9190000000" },
  { test: "Yes", name: "user2", number: "+9162000000" },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to modify each string of the original array, and [`string#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break each string into it's `key: value` pairs.

**Full code:**

```js
let arr = [
  "test: Yes, name: user1, number: +9190000000",
  "test: Yes, name: user2, number: +9162000000",
];

arr = arr.map((objStr) => {
  let object = {};

  objStr.split(",").forEach((pair) => {
    let [key, value] = pair.split(":");
    object[key.trim()] = value.trim();
  });

  return object;
});

console.log(arr);
```